# Is second-order logic with full semantics effectively checkable?

Tags: proof-verification, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

My question is simple.  Is second-order logic with full semantics (not Henkin semantics) effectively checkable?  That is, are the inference rules of second-order logic effective?

Comment: What does it mean to "check second-order logic", "setting aside individual sentence validity"?

Comment: Also what inference rules are you talking about?

Comment: (Maybe the question is whether there exists a set of inference rules for which we have soundness and completeness, as for FOL? I believe the answer to _that_ is no.)

Comment: No, I do not care about soundness and completeness.  I just want to know if second-order logic (with full syntax and semantics, not Henkin semantics) proof is effectively checkable assuming each sentence in the proof is valid.

Comment: _What_ syntax are you talking about? (I take it that here a "syntax" is a formal proof system? If not what do you mean? If so: Why would we care about a syntax that was not sound and complete?)

Comment: Regarding the inference rules, I did not specify them, so that becomes part of the question.  So, the question becomes what second-order inference rules are effectively checkable and does there exist a set of such inference rules that  use the full syntax and semantics of second-order logic?   It seems to me that all of the inference rules I have seen in second-order logic are effective (please correct me if I am wrong and you can provide a counterexample).

Comment: Regarding syntax, it is my understanding that there is a single syntax and semantics that goes by the name "the full syntax and semantics of second-order logic".  Several other people I have talked to on this site and others have referred to "the full syntax and semantics of second-order logic" without questioning which syntax is being referred to.

Comment: It you're somehow assuming that you already know which sentences are valid,  then what do you need inference rules for at all?

Comment: Saying that several other people have referred to "the full syntax and semantics of second-order logic" doesn't telll me what syntax you're talking about...

Comment: The wijipedia article on second-order logic says "The weakest deductive system that can be used consists of a standard deductive system for first-order logic (such as natural deduction) augmented with substitution rules for second-order terms.". Proofs  in that system are certainly effectively checkable.

Comment: @HenningMahkholm Yes, okay, I made a mistake.  I do not care about sentence validity (which is why I said assume they are valid, but I should have been more precise and said "disregarding validity").  What I care about is whether or not the inferences are effectively checkable.   I have been told that second-order logic cannot be reduced to first-order logic, but I have developed a proof that shows all effectively checkable calculi can be reduced to first-order logic.  I cannot explain the contradiction.  I know about...

Comment: @DavidUllrich Henkin semantics, but that does not explain why I am able to reduce other second-order logics, such as second-order logic with full syntax and semantics.

Comment: "I do not care about sentence validity [...] What I care about is whether or not the inferences are effectively checkable." I have no idea what this means. **Validity is a special case of inference**: saying that $\varphi$ is valid is just saying that it can be inferred from $\emptyset$. It sounds like you have a very specific sense of "inference" in mind here, different from semantic entailment, but until you tell us what that is this question isn't answerable.

Comment: Validity can only be inferred if the inference rule is true.  Generally, such an inference rule is not part of standard second-order logic.   So, yes, I am not interested in validity *unless* it happens to be a consequence of an effective inference rule.  But really, as you pointed out, validity is a special case inference, so I do not need to talk about it at all.  Hence, I do not care about it.  What I care about is inference and if that happens to imply validity, I simply do not care.

Answer (score 1):

Your question ultimately mixes two very different objects: the "full inference relation" $\models_{II}$ for second-order logic with the standard semantics, and any of the many "effective approximations" to this, which I'll denote by "$\vdash_{II}^i$" (the "$i$" emphasizing that there are lots of these: $\vdash_{II}^1,\vdash_{II}^2,\vdash_{II}^3,...$, which are in general not equivalent in any sense).

It's easy to check that $\models_{II}$ is **not effective in any sense**: the set of validities (= those sentences $\varphi$ satisfying $\emptyset\models_{II}\varphi$) is not r.e., or even arithmetically definable, or even hyperarithmetic, or ... etc. However, each of the $\vdash_{II}^i$s **is indeed effective**.

So as before, we run into the question: **what do you mean by inference**? You emphasize here and at your other question that you're interested in the full semantics, but the restricted entailment relations $\vdash_{II}^i$ are not complete with respect to that semantics; if they're what you're actually interested in, then you're not actually looking at the full semantics at all. It is true of course that each of the $\vdash_{II}^i$s are essentially first-order, but *when explicitly talking about the full semantics* they're not what people mean by "second-order inference." It's in this latter sense, by the way, that people (correctly) say that second-order logic can't be reduced to first-order logic, and this in no way contradicts the effectiveness of the much, much weaker $\vdash_{II}^i$s.

It's worth noting that some authors take "inference" or "proof" to presuppose a fixed effective deductive system (like [this quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-check-a-second-order-logic-proof-with-a-Turing-machine/answer/David-R-Jefferson), which in my opinion is misleading in an important way). In that case *you need to tell us what "second-order logic" is in this context*, since - unlike FOL - there are many natural effective deductive systems which are sound (but not complete) for the full semantics but which are non-equivalent.

I think the quora answer linked above is misleading precisely because glides over this point - it assumes that "second-order proof" is already something we've settled on a meaning for ("there are an infinite number of statements in second order logic that are universally valid and can be proved to be so"), while missing the point that as soon as we abandon the full semantics we don't have a default deduction relation anymore and need to pick one before we can say anything useful.

---

And lest one try to bootstrap: while (trivially) $\models_{II}$ is indeed the union of all its effective fragments - or at least, when we restrict attention to finite theories - the task of determining whether a proposed effective deduction system $\vdash_{II}^i$ is sound for the full semantics is just as complicated as *(actually, strictly more complicated than)* the "true" relation $\models_{II}$ itself.

Comment: I do not care about completeness or soundness.   Indeed, it is my whole purpose here to finally correct a huge mistake in mathematics.  Cantor's infinite sets are what is causing this whole mess of undecidability and systems that are not sound or complete.   My reduction should be about to demonstrate that as long as I can get a coherent definition for what "second-order logic" it is "impossible" to reduce.

Comment: @JohnJenkins Sorry, but I'm not interested in carrying on this conversation any further.

Comment: Okay, no conversation needed.  You give me an example of a second-order logic proof that you claim I cannot reduce to a first-order proof (under the mapping I described) and I will reduce it.  You must supply all of the rules of inference you used (or a way to generate them).  Fair enough?  That will settle this once and for all.

Comment: Second-order proofs are nothing more than symbolically emulated first-order proofs.